# What is the meaning of phrase "death to the"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Recently read an article which contains,

> ***Death to the*** macho is not a metaphor...

- What is the meaning of ***death to the*** here?
- Is it same as ***to the death***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Death to the *thing*"** is a call to end the aforementioned *thing*.

For example, "Death to apartheid" would be a call to end apartheid. "Death to the Daleks" on the other hand would mean a call to kill all the Daleks.

It is not the same as **"to the death".** This means a fight or struggle...

> Until one participant in a fight or struggle has died or been killed. [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+the+death)

Comment: Collins Dictionary defines "to the death" as "to the end of life": https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-the-death